# Shift the entire formula leftward in align environment

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I want one tag per line so I use `align` environment.
But the formula is too long in my case,

[image]

I want to shift the entire formula a little bit to the left.

**My attempt:**

```tex
\begin{align}
    \hspace*{-1cm}aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{align}
```

and

```tex
\hspace*{-1cm}
\begin{align}
    aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{align}
```

However, they don't change anything.

**I also tried**:

```tex
\begin{equation}
\hspace*{-1cm}
    \begin{aligned}
        aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

It do shift the formula but only one tag is produced.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome zo TeX.SE! You should provide complete small document with your equation, which reproduce your problem, Now we can only guess, that your equations are wider than text (column?) width, so you should consider to break them into two lines. Protruding them out of text are is bad idea, especially if your document has text in two columns.

Comment: @Zarko The latex template I use is for journal submission. It produces extra space before each equation. So my idea is just simply shifting the formula 1 or 2pt to the left so that the formula won't overflow

Comment: See my answer.  Imagine, that equation is in the right column, what you will do then? I discourage this since most of journals will retype your article and on obtained result you haven't any influence.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you again for your advice! adjustwidth` is good! But I will follow your advice to break my equation into two lines.  ^ ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, shift of equation outside of text area is bad idea. The outside part can overwrite text in the left column  or is mode in document spinner area. So I strongly suggest to break your equations into teo lines each...

Anyway, if you persist in your intention, you can do this by use of `nccmath` or `changepage` packages:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{fleqn}[-3em]
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
    \end{fleqn}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-3em}{}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        aaa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

After two compilation (required by `changepage`) the result is:

[image]

**Addendum:**
In lack of information about your document layout, from your code fragment can be concluded, that you actually have one long equation broken into two lines. Why you not break it in three lines? For example by use of the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa           \\
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    \\
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: Perfect !!  Thank you sooo much!!  The latex template I use produces extra space before each equation. So I think is acceptable to shift the formula 1 or 2pt to the left so that the formula won't overflow.  `adjustwidth` solve my problem !

Comment: @KimbingNg, it is not perfect, this is example of bad typography and pure guessing, what is your actually your problem. See addendum to my answer which contain one more possible solution.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help ! I will break my equation.  btw, Although shifting is not a perfect solution, ajustwidth is indeed a useful tool !  : )